# Add a new file upload when the user uploads a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

HTML/JS/jQuery beginner here.

Here is some HTML I have:

```
<form:hidden path="attachmentFile" id="attachment-file-location" value=""/>
<input type="file"
       id="attachedFile"
       onChange="uploadFile();"/>
```

And the relevent JS:

```
 var oMyForm = new FormData();
 oMyForm.append("file", attachedFile.files[0]);
 $.ajax({
    //some stuff
    data: oMyForm,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#attachment-file-location").val(data);
    }
 });
```

This works well, but I want the user to be able to upload as many files as they want, and a new file upload will appear whenever they uploaded a file. To do this, I tried adding this code:

```
 var $newFileUpload = $("<input type=\"file\" id=\"attachedFile\" onChange=\"uploadFile();\"/>");
  $('#myDiv').append($newFileUpload);
```

Because this uses the same ID as the previous code, I won't be able to use this to actually upload multiple files.

On the UI and JS side, how can I handle the concept of multiple files better? On the JS side, how should I generate the new html file inputs?

Comment: add the _multiple_ attrib to the file input for a non-PITA way to upload many files.

Comment: Instead of using an `id`, why not use a `class`?

Answer (score 0):

What browsers are you using? If you add the attribute "multiple" to your input, your user will be able to select as many files as they want. Your input would then look like something this:

```
<input type="file" id="attachedFile" onChange="uploadFile();" multiple />
```